# jquery validation is not working while already declared inside jquery validation to restrict on special characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Need to be display side by side two field and i made that well but
I want to reduce little bit more space between the side by side field
and i'm using jquery validation but it is not working.
i want whenever user enter special character into the contact field display the error like only digit can be enter.
here is my code.

```js
$.validator.addMethod('decimal', function(value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^((\d+(\\.\d{0,2})?)|((\d*(\.\d{1,2}))))$/.test(value);
}, "Please enter a correct number, format 0.00");
$().ready(function () {
// validate signup form on keyup and submit
$("#signup").on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#log').text('Form is valid? ' + $(this).valid().toString());
});
$("#signup").validate({
rules: {
FirstName:{
required:true,
minlength: 3,
maxlength:50
}, 
LastName:{
required: true,
minlength: 3,
maxlength:50
}, 
Address1:{
minlength: 3,
maxlength:100,
regex : /^[#.0-9a-zA-Z\s,-]+$/
},
PhoneMobile :{
minlength:10,
maxlength:12,
regex : /^[0-9]+$/
}
},
messages: {
FirstName:{
required: "Please Enter Ur First Name",
minlength: 'please enter atleast three character',
maxlength: 'Please do not enter more than 50 words' 
},
LastName:{
required: "Please enter your last name",
minlength: 'please enter atleast three character',
maxlength: 'Please do not enter more than 50 words' 
},
Address1:{
minlength: 'please enter atleast three character',
maxlength: 'Please do not enter more than 50 words',
regex: 'Please do not enter special character'
},
PhoneMobile :{
minlength:'Please enter atleast 10 digits',
maxlength:'Please do not enter more than 12 digits',
regex: 'Please enter only digits'
}
},
submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
alert('valid form');
return false;
}
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <style type="text/css">
         label {  float: left; margin: 0 -10px 0 0; padding-left: 15%; padding-top: 5%; }
         span { display: block; margin: 0 0 3px; font-size: 0.8em; font-weight: bold; color: gray; }
         .sizing { width: 300px; border: 1px solid gray; padding: 10px; }
      </style>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.10.0/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form id="signup" name="signup" method="POST" action="#">
         <label for="company">
         <span>Company First</span>
         <input name="FirstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name"id="FirstName" tabindex="1"style="color:Gray;" class="sizing" />
         </label>
         <label for="contact">
         <span>Contact Second</span>
         <input name="LastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name" id="LastName" tabindex="2" 
            class="sizing" style="color:Gray;" />
         </div>
         </label>
         <label for="contact">
         <span>Contact third</span>
         <input name="Address1" type="text" placeholder="Address1" id="Address1" tabindex="3" 
            class="sizing"/>
         </label>
         <label for="contact">
         <span>Contact Fifth</span>
         <input name="PhoneMobile" type="text" id="PhoneMobile" tabindex="4" class="sizing" placeholder="contact number" />
         </label>
         <label for="contact">
         <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit">  
         </label>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

As you see,
there is more gab between the input field i just want to reduce little bit more gab from them.
and i don't know why my validation is not working.

Comment: Please describe exactly how it is not working.

Comment: facing two problem 1. want to reduce size between the fields. 2. jquery validation is not working